# Firebase with kotlin array of ratings problem

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I cant get the ratings all at the same time and do the average! Anyone knows how to do this? Get a problem saying "none of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied"

```
val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("recipes/$id/reci_ratings/")
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            p0.children.forEach{
                val rt= it.child("rating").value
                val numbers = arrayOf(rt)
                var sum = 0
                for (element in numbers) {
                    sum += element
                }
                val average = sum / numbers.size
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot. Please also tell us what is the value of `id` inside your reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to lack the closing bracket with parenthesis, but maybe you just missed to add that in your question?

Another thing is that your numbers array will never contain more than one ratings value. You should declare and populate it like so:

```
val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("recipes/$id/reci_ratings/")
var numbers: ArrayList<Int> = arrayListOf() // Change to whatever type is accurate in your case
var sum = 0

ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
        p0.children.forEach {
            val rt = it.child("rating").value
            numbers.add(rt)
            
        }

        // After the forEach loop is finished you should have all the ratings in the numbers array
        
    }
})
```

Comment: The numbers variable says the integer literal does not conform to the expected type kotlin.colections..